# Can "taste" be used as a participle

Tags: grammar

The food, ______ good, was soon sold out when it was taken to the market.

A. being tasted B. tasted C. having tasted D. tasting

Comment: I'm confused by you asking one thing in the title of your question, but then presenting some kind of multiple choice in the body of your question. What do you really want to know? As it stands, this look like homework (or proofreading) rather than anything else.

Comment: Well, it has to be in participle form, all of the options are. Though here I would say it would be an attributive verb phrase, and people differ as to whether that's the progressive participle or the gerund (seeing as they look the same).

So, as the question suggests, you can use some form of taste here. What's your difficulty with knowing which one to use?

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence would make sense if you used "which tasted". "The food, which tasted good, was soon..."

You could also say "The good-tasting food was soon..."

That may not answer your question about participles, but really any verb can be used as a participle